# Как заставить работать якоря при ajax подгрузке?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, реализовал AJAX подгрузку секций лендинга при прокрутке. Реализовал подгрузку посекционно. Секции успешно запрашиваются поочередно с сервера и добавляются в документ посредством `$("section:last").after(data);`

Но появилась проблема: на каждой секции лендинга стоит якорь и на этот якорь завязан пункт меню.

Вопрос: Как реализовать навигацию, если по факту ни одна(при старте) или несколько(при просморе) секций недоступны для просмотра, а пользователь уже кликает по их якорям?

Comment: Самый простой вариант: создать функцию, которая будет запускать прокрутку по клику на якорь. Эта функция вызывается в document.ready, а потом каждый раз после ajax-подгрузки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css + jquery Вам в помощь, не занимайтесь ерундой... Зачем запрашивать файлы если можно их скрыть и показывать в любом порядке и когда хотите... Тем более такой код навредит СЕО, так как робот будет видеть только кусок непонятного кода...

Comment: заказчик потребовал "как ВК", ну я ему и не отказал =) Спасибо за наставление на верный путь. Обе проблемы решились буквально 10 строками кода!